# Understanding to build a sliding/swiping web app using css3 and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I was following through this [tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/) on building a slide/swipe web app using css3 and jquery. Although the article was thorough with its explanation, I am having a very difficult time to understand some of the concepts. Pardon me if these questions are very noob, but I really want to learn.

You can see the demo and the code here at [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/karlars/pen/yeYdLj).

I am having problem to understand with these two functions:

Function 1: `function slide()`

Inside the `slide()`, what is the `touchPixelRatio` about? And isn't the `deltaSlide` enough to `translate()` the `#slides`?

```
if (sliding == 2) {
    var touchPixelRatio = 1;
    if ((currentSlide == 0 && event.clientX > startClientX) || (currentSlide == slideCount - 1 && event.clientX < startClientX))
        touchPixelRatio = 3;
    pixelOffset = startPixelOffset + deltaSlide / touchPixelRatio;
    $('#slides').css('transform', 'translate3d(' + pixelOffset + 'px,0,0)').removeClass();
}
```

Function 2: `function slideEnd()`

How did the `#slides` translated when there was no `.animate` class before? The `.animate` class was only added later after the `translate` line.

```
$('<style id="temp">#slides.animate{transform:translate3d(' + pixelOffset + 'px,0,0)}</style>').appendTo('head');
$('#slides').addClass('animate').css('transform', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `touchPixelRatio` is a the amount of movement the user has to make with their mouse or finger in order for the image to slide 1 pixel. When you are on the first slide and sliding to the right or on the last slide and sliding to the left it just gives the effect of pulling but not being able to pull as far as you want. It stops after some time (when you hit the edge of browser window). In the article they describe it as a rubber band effect which seems like a good enough name honestly. Essentially it just means for every 3 pixels your mouse moves the image only moves 1 pixel. `deltaSlide` is enough to do the job but if they want the movement to sliding ratio to be a bit smaller so that on the end slides and moving in a direction such that there are no more slides to see to seem like it lets you pull only so far before it stops, like a rubber band, they added this `touchPixelRatio`.
2. They pulled the the previous animation off using inline styles which is why in those last two lines of code they dynamically generate a new class with transform values, insert it into the DOM, then add the animate class and remove any inline styles that would override the newly added class. In fact if you look at the `slide` function you can see where they are applying inline styles and also removing any classes on it (most likely the `animate` class since calling `removeClass` without any arguments removes all classes from an element):

   ```
   $('#slides').css('transform', 'translate3d(' + pixelOffset + 'px,0,0)').removeClass();
   ```

That will apply those values directly to the element which will override any class styling. So in order for the `animate` class to take effect they remove those inline styles after adding the `animate` class.